# Unidentified clicking sound coming from front wheel area when performing an endo

Tags: fork, hub, noise, clicking, brake-noise

I have recently bought a Canyon Strive CF and have had no problems or crashes on it. However, there is an unpredictable clicking sound coming from the front wheel area (not sure whether it's from the forks, brakes, hub or even perhaps the headset). The sound only occurs when I do an endo using the front brake and even then it is not a sound which happens every time, it is only on every fifth or tenth endo, it is quite a sharp and loud click that doesnt sound too healthy. I've thoroughly inspected the frame for cracks and think it is safe to say I can rule that out due to both the inconsistency of the noise and the fact that I haven't found even a hint of a crack. Does anyone know what this might be?

Cheers Edward

P.S. if it is part specific then it may be helpful to know what components I have:

Fork: Fox Float 34 Performance

Brakes: Hope Tech E4

Front disc: Hope tech

Front hub: Novatec

Front wheel: WTB i25 KOM

Headset: Nukeproof

Comment: Have you fully inspected the front wheel, looking for loose spokes or cracks in the rim, especially around spoke holes?

Comment: Can you recreate the noise without doing an endo? Are you sure it's coming from the front? Noises are deceptive, I rode for a couple of hours the other week with a constant ticking noise which I thought was from the front end somewhere, turned out to be my shoe lace hitting the pedal every turn of the crank

Comment: Some ideas to narrow it down: Can you reproduce the click without braking, for example pushing the bike against a wall (not crashing)? If yes, can you reproduce the click with front wheel removed?

Comment: Wheel looks in fine condition, small play in the spokes but only millimeters (think that's to be expected?) and no cracks that I've found. Pretty sure the noise is from the front it only occurs when I'm moving about on the front wheel not when back hopping or doing a wheelie.

Comment: I dont seem to be able to reproduce it with the front wheel off but haven't managed to endo against a wall since I dont have a convenient one close by, hoping to try that soon. I also still got the noise with the forks locked out so it's not due to play there, although I have heard that fox forks can produce clicking from the join between the stanchion and crown?

Comment: I was going to suggest checking your headset and fork/steerer/stem relationship for slack, but then I read on noticed you have a Fox fork. If it's not the fork, I would Still Pull the fork out, inspect your headset and look for anything that could cause slack between the head tube ID and the headset, headset to steerer, etc. I had a loud Sharp click noise in my carbon cyclocross frame. Carbon fiber bikes have great acoustic properties. It could be something small but sound big. And it might be hard to reproduce the tick without your body weight on the bike, which makes it harder to diagnose.

Comment: Ok thanks very much for the advice, I think it sounds likely it is coming from the headset area

Answer (score 1):

Could it be the spokes rubbing over eachother? You can check the tension of the spokes by squeezing parallel pairs together.

My fixie bike makes a clicking noise sometimes when the wheel needs tensioning and I'm pedalling backwards.